# Facebook mobile login with PHP SDK

Tags: php, android, facebook

I could get Facebook token from Android device and post the value to the web server.

When I used Facebook PHP SDK, it was easy to get facebook user information.

```
// Get User ID
$fb_id = $this->facebook->getUser();

// Get User Info
$user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
```

Just this one line gave me all the information.

I have no idea how to get a user information by using only facebook token that I get from mobile.

```
// get mobile token
$fb_token = $this->input->post('fb_token');

$user_info = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$fb_token;
```

Ok. so It looks like I get joson data if I use above url address.

How can I bring the array data into the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile"? iOS? Android? or maybe mobile web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user has authenticated ([SSO](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso)) you can simply use the [Facebook object](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java) to make requests:

```
facebook.request("me", new RequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {}

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {}

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {}

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
});
```

You can make synced requests: [API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) or asynced: [Async API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/)

Answer (score 0):

you need add just one line and you are done.

```
$userData = file_get_contents($user_info);
```